# Is it right to have two related MVC projects on the same solution?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, projects-and-solutions

I have no experience in Visual Studio and projects and solutions management so I'm asking your guidance if I'm in the right direction or completely off base.

I'm about to start development of two ASP.NET MVC applications that will use the same business layer: **Site1** is a huge intranet site and **Site2** is an authentication based website where our company's customers will have access to some info. **Site2** will expose a small subset of **Site1** functionalities and will have a very different layout.

After some thinking I structured my solutiong this way:

**Company** (solution)

- **Company.Core:** entities, repositories, services
- **Company.Core.Tests**
- **Company.MVC1:** intranet, references Company.Core
- **Company.MVC2:** customers website, references Company.Core

Am I right in organizing my projects this way or should I do things different? I'm open for suggestions...

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure you need two projects. You could likely get away with one project, and using a subset of the 'Theme' system, use ActionFilters to decide which views to render and which features to allow. http://pietschsoft.com/post/2009/03/ASPNET-MVC-Implement-Theme-Folders-using-a-Custom-ViewEngine.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are working on ASP.NET MVC 2 or above, you can prefer to use [Areas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for small project as part of Large project.

Areas provides way to go make your large project into small partition of project which provides `views`, `model` and `controller` for each Area.....

I personally, find it very useful in large project.....

Comment: I first thought about Areas, but they won't work for us. For exapmle the authentication mechanism will be different, **App1** will use an LDAP server, **App2** probably the default membership provider or another LDAP server. Another thing is that domains will be different for App1 and App2.

Comment: Each area can have its own web configuration file where you can override authentication according to your need...